# Google Home - Streaming hls to chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-smart-home

I've implemented smart home service for camera, including SYNC, QUERY, EXECUTE. Execute response is returning adequate hls url. However, casting that stream to Android tv via chromecast results in black screen.

Do I need some configuration to be able to stream hls?
Also, I have another question.
Is it possible to watch stream inside Google Home application on phone?

Answer (score 0):

Chromecast supports hls protocol for video streaming now. A possible reason for the
black screen during casting the stream on Android TV using google chromecast can
be due to the usage of the custom driver instead of the generic driver. It would be
great to check if the streaming works fine with a generic driver. More information in
regards to this can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming).

Comment: Can you explain, what do you mean about custom or generic drivers? Where I can specify which driver should be used? If I use the same hls URL in the VLC player (on Android TV), it results in showing the stream, but directly via Chromecast is a black screen.